# How can I position excerpt image like this?

Tags: css, image, alignment, genesis

Good evening,

It is my first time building a website.
On my home page I list the most recent articles.
In the excerpt, I have the title, image, and beginning of the article.

I am using the Genesis template and more specifically "Minimum Pro".

[Here is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4biM.jpg) (my site is : parlons-survivalisme.com)

[And here is what I want][2] (as you can see, the image is under the title/description, and left of the text)

I wouldn't bother asking the question but I spent 4 hours trying to find out how to do this and at this point while I'm sure it's possible, I have no idea how it can be done.

I have played with margins, position, float, but nothing has worked..

Thank you for your time and help !

Comment: Since ti's wordpress, it's better to check the available option carefully or try to restruct the layout, CSS won't be enough here

Comment: The changes you want imply modifying the template. Most likely, that template is a separate file in your parent theme. You need to find it in the parent theme, place it in the child theme with exact same name and folder path as in parent theme and make your mods to it. After you're happy with the mods to markup you can finish it up with CSS. While not extremely complicated, it would be fair to say it's a task for someone with decent understanding of WordPress and of general web development concepts.

Comment: In addition to the above, your chances of getting help here are quite low, as it's an environment that's difficult to reproduce. Take me, for example. I know WordPress well. It would be an easy job if I had the theme installed and I had you by my side to tell me exactly what you want. But, as it is, it's impossible for me to provide an answer, as I don't have all the required information.